# Searching for literal characters with Firefox’ find feature

Tags: firefox, search, special-characters, characters

When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find the character `’`, Firefox also finds `'` (and vice versa).

This was not the case in older Firefox versions (I don’t know exactly since when this happens).

I understand that this is useful in most cases, but I want to find the actual characters I entered, not "equivalent" characters. **How can I get back the old behaviour?** Is there an `about:config` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change was made to Firefox in 2013 in response to a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276757). The bug history shows requests for an option to switch the feature off, but they have been declined as “too edge-casey”. In an answer to a [question](https://support.mozilla.org/fi/questions/987010) on Mozilla support forum, a script based on the Greasemonkey extension has been suggested.

The simplest way around the problem is probably to use a different browser when needed. Chrome seems to have the same feature as Firefox, but IE 11 treats Ascii apostrophe ' and typographer’s apostrophe ’ as two distinct characters.